# Optimal use of datetime related objects in python-polars - should I be using pl.date or other alternatives?

Tags: python-polars

I am working with many reasonably large polar dataframes (1m - 200m records) and many of these are time-indexed using dates.

To clarify, I never care about timezones or the time component of the date, all the data is daily.

So far I've been using the `pl.Date()` column type as this seems optimal, but now I am second guessing myself.

As of polars 1.6 it's no longer possible to compare `pl.Date()` columns to date strings (eg. `'2020-01-01'`)

So I'll be refactoring a fair amount of my code to explicitly use either `np.datetime64` objects, or `pl.date` or `pl.datetime` objects.

Is there any good reason to prefer one of these over another? They are all fairly comparable in the benchmarking I've done for `.filter` operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare with `datetime.date` - `pl.Date` should be fine

e.g.

```
import datetime as dt

df.filter(pl.col('date') > dt.date(2000, 1, 1))
```

instead of

```
df.filter(pl.col('date') > '2000-01-01')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm doing now. In pandas I found support for datetime.date objects was fairly poor, do you think pl.Date is well supported in polars or should I be using datetime objects?

Comment: yeah should be! I think in pandas the issue with dt.date is when indexing, but polars doesn't have an index so that's not an issue :)

Comment: At the cost of going into a rant: pandas doesn't really handle datetime.date objects, under the hood they are always either np.datetime64 objects or just "objects" - it is also very funny when working with pd.NaT onbjects (which can be compared to datetime[64] but not to date objects.

Comment: yeah polars does a lot less (if any?) hacking around with its dependencies' internals, so it should be more reliable (especially as people start using it more and whatever bugs exist get reported and fixed!)